# Python на хостинге не удается сделать миграцию

Tags: python, django

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь произвести миграцию БД. Создал через консоль новое приложение.

```
python xxxx/manage.py startapps frontmodule
```

После добавил в `models.py` значения. 
Добавил в `settings.py` в `INSTALLED_APPS 'frontmodule.apps.FrontmoduleConfig'`.
Пытаюсь произвести миграцию

```
python xxxx/manage.py makemigration
```

И выбивает ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontmodule'`

Что я делаю не так?
На локальном сервере все работает.

Comment: `frontmodule` попробуйте вместо `frontmodule.apps.FrontmoduleConfig`

Comment: Пути. Если разница только лишь в окружении, а не в коде, то стоит проверить всевозможные пути: pythonpath, django_settings_module

Answer (score 1):

После тонны прочитанных однообразных документаций и серфинг по иностранным форумам, я решил проблему самым забавным способ.
Хостинг, на котором я разместился, оставил хороший мануал по `Django` и установки, но не учел тот факт, что при `python xxxx/manage.py startapp nameapp` приложение создавалось не возле `manage.py`, а за папкой всего `django` проекта.
Из-за этого и выбивало ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontmodule'` и ей подобные, что не удалось обнаружить модуль. 
Следить за правильной иерархией папок проекта - это оказывается, очень важно и не верьте автоматически созданной иерархии, она может подвести.

Старый вид папок:

```
---->www/
-->mysite.ru/
->djangoSite(где находится сам manage.py)
->frontmodule
```

Новый вид папок:

```
---->www/
-->mysite.ru/
->djangoSite(где находится сам manage.py)/
>frontmodule
>djangoSite
```

Comment: видимо вам стоило запускать startapp из папки проекта, что логично. вы сами допустили ошибку и сами решили. молодец :)

Comment: так я так и запуска python папкапроекта/manage.py startapp nameApp
но увы
Пришлось вручную перетаскивать папки

Comment: не правильно. надо было зайти в папку проекта, где находится manage.py и  оттуда фигачить